# In After Effects, how do I enable the handles of the bezier curve in the graph editor, for "Position" in a "Transform" effect?

Tags: after-effects

I am unable to use the handles of the bezier curves with a *Effect > Distort > Transform*'s *Position*, whereas I can do that just fine using the layer's *Transform*. Does anyone know why?

[image: bezier curve no handle]

[image: bezier curve handles]

Comment: Weird.. you're right. Maybe a bug?

Comment: Is it because you can't “Separate Dimensions” in the effect?